# Mixing ITT and TOT/LATE Effect Sizes in Meta-Analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, effect-size, treatment-effect, meta-regression, systematic

I have a question concerning the coding of Effect Sizes for a large (educational) Meta Analysis with mostly latent outcome variables.

Some studies provide "Intent to Treat" Data from which I calculate Effect Sizes (Hedges g) and some studies only provide (local average treatment effect) LATE or TOT (treatment on treated) Data. Some studies report both.

**Is it okay to mix ITT and LATE Treatment-Effects-Data or should I stick to one type of treatment operationalization?**

My meta analysis is concerned with educational interventions and since we seek to explain the variability in treatment success of these interventions afterwards through Intervention characteristics I usually would prefer to include the estimates of the subjects who really completed the intervention (rather than who were assigned to the treatment).

Answer (score 1):

Including both should be fine but since you are planning to use meta-regression then it would seem a good idea to include another (binary) moderator: ITT versus LATE.